# @Output from service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-services

I am using Angular CLI. Actually, I have a service. This service return variable *answer* . I would like to use the variable in app-component(or dublicate of the variable). So when *answer* change, It must be seen in the app-component. Now I can see onle initiial value of the variable and don't see changed *answer*.

service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate }    from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class LogInGuardService implements CanActivate {


public answer: boolean;
public i: number = 0;


    canActivate() {
        let entered = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('enteredValue'));

        let enteredEmail = entered.email_field;
        let enteredPw = entered.password_field;
        let guardChange = false;
        for (var i = 1; i < localStorage.length; i++) {

            let stored = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
            let storedEmail = stored.email_field;
            let storedPw = stored.password_field;


            if ( enteredEmail == storedEmail )  {

                if ( enteredPw == storedPw ) {
                    this.answer = true;


                } else {
                    alert('Неверный пароль');
                    this.answer = false;
                }

            } else {
                this.i++;
            }
        }

        if (this.i == localStorage.length-1) {
            alert('Пользователя с таким e-mail не существует');
        }
    return this.answer;
  }

  constructor() { }

}
```

app-component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LogInGuardService } from './log-in-guard.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    public guardInMain: boolean;

    constructor(private loginService: LogInGuardService) {

        this.guardInMain = true;

        this.guardInMain = !this.loginService.answer;

    }
    }
```

Comment: You are getting the value once, when the constructor is invoked, what you need to do, is publish the changes of that value, working with RxJS from your service (Subject, BehaviourSubject), and so on... On this way, your "guardInMain" value will be updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to store some variable in your service you can use Observables for that.

Use [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/BehaviorSubject.js~BehaviorSubject.html) for that. Subject is both observable and observer. So you can tell it there is a new answer and it will notify all subscribers.

In your service:

```
answer$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
getAnswer(): Observable<string> {
    return this.answer$.asObservable();
}

giveAnswer(answer: string) {
    this.answer$.next(answer);
}
```

Notice that constructor accepts the initial value.

You can set new answer:

```
AnswerService.giveAnswer('this is my answer');
```

And you can subscribe anywhere for value changes:

```
AnswerService.getAnswer().subscribe(answer => console.log(answer));
```

Comment: You should return `this.answer$.asObservable();` as exposing the subject is asking for trouble. That also makes the type annotation superfluous incidentally

Comment: @AluanHaddad you are definitely right. Thank you. I've learnt something new :-)